# Windows Mobile autoscroll doesn't work

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a long text inside a Label in a panel (Windows Mobile 6.5). I set the panel's autoscroll property to true and see the scroll bar but it doesn't work, I can't scroll it. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the following and it works fine:

1. Add a Panel to the Form
2. Set the Panel `Size` to `100x100`
3. Set `AutoScroll` to `true`
4. Drag a Label into the Panel
5. Set the Label `Size` to `50x200`

Then run the project and the ScrollBar is visible and it can be dragged up and down.

The only reason that the Panel wouldn't scroll if it is set to `Enabled = false;`.